# Showing degree of algebraic closure is infinite

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, unique-factorization-domains

$R$ is a UFD, but not a field, and $K=Quot(R)$. Show that $[\bar{K}:K]=\infty$ where $\bar{K}$ is the algebraic closure of K.

I am not sure how to approach this problem. Any hint is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $R$ is a UFD different of a field, you have an element $p$ which is irreducible, thus $p$ is a prime. The Eisenstein criterion applied to integral domain: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion#Generalized_criterion

implies that $X^n-p, n>1$ is irreducible in $R[X]$. This implies that $X^n-p$ is irreducible in $K[X]$ see the same reference. Thus for each $n>0$, $F$ as an extension of degree $n$ $F[X]/(X^n-p)$ so its algebraic closure is infinite since if $F$ is finite of cardinal $f$, $F[X]/(X^n-p)$ is a $F$-vector space of dimension $F$ which has dimension  $f^n$.

Comment: Very nice, Tsemo!